# ClojureScript self referencing

Tags: javascript, clojurescript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to convert from JavaScript to ClojureScript some simple examples to familiarize myself with ClojureScript, but for the hell of it I'm unable to wrap my head around this [snippet](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/06-render-text):

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'example', { create: create });

function create() {
    var text = "- phaser -\n with a sprinkle of \n pixi dust.";
    var style = { font: "65px Arial", fill: "#ff0044", align: "center" };

    var t = game.add.text(game.world.centerX-300, 0, text, style);
}
```

to:

```
;; Uncaught ReferenceError: game is not defined
(defn create []
  (let [text "- phaser -\n with a sprinkle of \n pixi dust."
        style (js-obj "font" "65px Arial" "fill" "#ff0044" "align" "center")]
    (game.add.text (- game.world.centerX 300) 0 text style)))

(def game (js/Phaser.Game. 800 600 js/Phaser.CANVAS "example" #js {:create create}))
```

The problem is that I'm also trying to self reference the to-be defined object from a function in ClojureScript - and I've got a feeling that this isn't right and/or idiomatic thinking in ClojureScript, so how does one approach such a situation?

EDIT:

```
;; Working example
(declare game)

(defn create []
  (let [text "- phaser -\n with a sprinkle of \n pixi dust."
        style (js-obj "font" "65px Arial" "fill" "#ff0044" "align" "center")]
    (.text game.add (- (.-centerX game.world) 300) 0 text style)))

(def game (js/Phaser.Game. 800 600 js/Phaser.CANVAS "example"  #js {:create create}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clojure will not pick up the definition after the function, so it's out of scope. You can put it in scope, move it to above the function, or `declare` it at the top of your file.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/declare

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. Your suggestion has worked and I was incorrectly accessing/calling the nested js object properties. I have edited my question with a working example. Thank you.